# How to kill stickers, sandburrs, goatheads, in Bermuda grass lawn

Tags: lawn

How to kill stickers, sandburrs, goatheads, in Bermuda grass lawn
I remember a post mentioning something about treating while grass was dormant. I just don’t remember what chemical and how often? Please help

Answer (score 1):

You can apply the chemical called 2,4-Dichlorophenoxyacetic acid.  It is commonly referred to as 2-4-D.  It must be used when the plants are actively growing.  It will only kill broadleaf weeds, which is normally all dicotyledons, AKA dicots. It will not kill grass or damage most Monocotyledons, AKA monocots. 
[Wikipedia article on 2-4-D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2,4-Dichlorophenoxyacetic_acid)

You can apply when bermuda grass is completely dormant glyphosate, AKA Roundup Brand.  The bermuda grass must be completely brown in the upper canopy of the grass. It's best to apply it to selectively, not broadcast across the whole lawn.
[Video on apply glyphosate to dormant bermuda grass](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PoTpB9F0vzI)

Comment: Thank you for answering. I have 3 lots surrounding my home and they are basically just Bermuda and lots of beautiful green stickers LOL. I live in West Texas and it hasn’t gotten really cold yet and i still see green at the root of my Bermuda. I was told stickers germinate under ground during these cold months and spraying them now and again early sprint is the only way to kill them. I’m just concerned about my Bermuda being dormant and my ability to know it. I will refer to the links above. I appreciate your insight

Comment: If the tops of the bermuda grass is brown, its dormant.  If the spray hit the dormant brown grass, it can not be absorbed.  It will not kill the bermuda grass.   But, still try to be selective, don't just spray the whole yard.  Spray the green plants.  Those are actively growing ish.  I say ish because the plant is growing slower than in the active season.

Comment: Since, the weather is cold it will take the spray longer to work.  It will take time for the plant to move the spray from the leaves to the roots.  You will not notice results in a few days or a week like you might normally, but you will start to see the weed start to brown with time.     The bermuda may never go completely brown to the ground, because the canopy it keeping that lower part warm, keeping the frost off of it.    If you wait until it gets too cold, the spray will not be as effective.  So, if the canopy is brown, then its time to go spray the weeds.